# Dead threads on a default.NET 4.5 windows service

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-services

We have a .NET 4.0 windows service that has been in used for quite some time now. The windows service basically processes a lot of files using background threads. We use the ThreadPool class and never the Thread class. When the windows service started suffering performance degradation, one of the steps we took was to get a dump of the process using DebugDiag. The report indicated that the process has dead threads. The number of dead threads also varies from each dump.

After some research, we came across an entry explaining that dead threads are managed thread objects where the underlying native thread no longer exist. Is it possible that these dead threads are just the managed threads within the ThreadPool? If so, why would the ThreadPool have managed threads that are already dead.

To further investigate the cause of our dead threads, we tried analyzing a dump of a blank windows service. In this exercise we constantly saw 3 dead threads on the report. The windows service that we used is the default windows service created using Visual Studio 2012 with no user code, blank OnStart and OnStop methods, no finalizer and additional library references aside from the ones added by VS2012.

The following are our main concerns on dead threads:
 - Are these dead threads normal to any .NET Windows Services? 
 - What normally causes dead threads?
 - Do dead threads cause any memory leak? 
 - Do dead threads cause CPU to be underutilized?
 - Should we be concerned about these dead theads at all?

Comment: Dead threads are managed thread objects where the underlying native thread does not exist. In you're case I suspect the dead threads are threads disposed by the threadpool while resizing, which are pending to be cleaned up by the GC. Try and force the GC to collect for all generations and the dead threads should disappear.

Comment: I tried calling GC.Collect() in the OnStart() method of the default windows service but the dead threads are still there.

Comment: Did you consider the collect triggering the finalizer, therefore requiring another collect to free the memory? If thats not the case then a memory leak is a good possibility

Comment: I didn't explicitly define any finalizer. The service that I'm testing is just the default windows service project created with VS2012. There are no user code within the project. The OnStart() and OnStop() methods of the Service class are blanks. It's really curious that a new windows service project will have 3 dead threads immediately.

Comment: I thought Managed Threads didn't necessarily correspond to underlying native threads. Do you have "proof" these Threads are "dead"?

Comment: I can only say your intepretation of the dumps is incorrect. If you are not capable of analyzing dumps, make sure you find an expert or contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com. I don't mean to be rude, but you are wasting your own time.

Comment: It's actually written in DebugDiag's report under the .NET Threads Summary (ThreadCount:5, UnstartedThread:0, BackgroundThread:1, PendingThread:0, DeadThread:3). We've already sent an email to MS and we're waiting for their reply now.